# QGIS 3.26 is messing with my project files

Tags: qgis-3, windows-10, save

At some point, not from a fresh install,  when I open a **qgz** file, from within the program or from windows explorer (Win.10), it opens some layers from that project and some layers from another project (that I was working on two months ago). The missing vector files, which have been replaced by the vector files of the older project, have the same names ("P" for points for example) but they are in different directories.

- I added the missing files, redo the styling, and saved as different names, and in qgs format, with the same results. It is the third project that does that mess.
- I uninstalled and reinstalled Qgis but it has the same problem.
- Is there something else to do before I decide to install  Q 3.28 or Q 3.22 LTR with the hope, that it won't have the same problem? A directory to clean/delete files?

EDIT 21/4/2023 After 2 months of using Qgis it didn't happened again so I guess it is not a common problem. If you want you can close/delete this question.

Comment: Did it only happen with layer that have the same name but are in different folder ? What option did you use for Default paths (Relative or absolute) ?

Comment: Also I would suggest to not give the same name to different dataset or even copy of the same dataset...

Comment: J.R.   yes it is like it has kept  two vector names and files from that old project (I am naming from the year 2014 P for points, L for lines with no problem) and in my new projects after saving, closing and opening again the programm, instead of the new vectors it appears the old ones. But it keeps the extent boundaries of the new project. It's somehow funny. Only those two vector types. The default path is relative in my options.